# CGI GET PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, cgi

I currently have a HTML/PHP form redirect variables and it's values to Python via GET:

```
 </script>
     <form id="form" target="_blank" style="display:none;" action="result.py" method="get">
     </form>
```

The output of which results looking like this: 
http://www.server.com/result.py?option=1&option2=2

I'm able to catch the settings coming through with PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET)){
        foreach($_GET as $k => $v){
                echo $k . ' = ' .$v. '<br/>';
        }
}
```

But would really like to have this info capture in Python and I'm not sure where to start.

The only thing I could think of is having all the possible variables in Python and filter the ones coming in.

What I'm really after is a Python catching the variables given in the URL and nothing more.

A push in the right direction would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Python via CGI? It's been supported for a very long time.

This tutorial should set you on the right path:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

It answers your question, plus a whole lot more.